# NodeJs typescript FormData - Enviar archivo .zip

Tags: nodejs, axios, zip, formdata

Ya perdi mas de 8 horas intentando resolver esto y lo cierto es que no puedo retrasarme mas.

Tengo dos funciones de backend diferentes, una recibe un file csv y lo procesa, y otra recibe un archivo .zip y lo procesa. Ambas funciones estan ok y funcionan como deben. Al tirar los files desde POSTMAN obtengo los resultados esperados.

El problema es cuando quiero hacerlo desde typescript.

Realicé un método que envía el csv a la función, y funciona de maravilla, sin embargo hice un metodo (identico al anterior) que envía el .zip, pero el post de axios siempre devuelve error 500.

Intuyo que el problema radica en la forma en que envío el .zip. Sin mas, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
var formData = new FormData();
        var address = localhost:8000/processZip;
        var file = await fs.createReadStream(./file.zip);
        var _this = this;

        formData.append('file', file);
        var headers = formData.getHeaders();

        formData.pipe(concat((data:any) => {

            axios.post(address, data, {"headers":headers}).then((response:any) => {
                let message = 'File was imported successfully';
                console.log(message);
                console.log(response);
            }).catch((error:any) => {
                console.log('AXIOS fails on POST. Error: ');
                console.log(error);
            });
        }));
```

Agradecería cualquier orientación por favor!